# How to extract sub object from rest api response in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is `employee.component.ts`:

```
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit 
{
    empResponseList: EmpResponse[];

    showEmps() {
        this.paymentService.getAllEmps().subscribe((data: EmpResponse[]) => {
               this.empResponseList = data;

                                                                                            
   });
}
```

This is we are getting as response  data = [employee:{},department[] ] -->from this we need to extra department[] in component it self.

This is `EmployeeService.ts`:

```
getAllEmps(): Observable<EmpResponse[]> 
{
    return this.http.get<EmpResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + `/api/emps`);
}
```

This is `EmployeeResponse` model in Angular:

```
 export class EmpResponse {
      department: Department;
      employee: Employee[];
    }
```

When I call the `showEmps()` method it will return

Comment: I don't understand the question correctly but can't you just access the department using data.department? A stackblitz example would be great.

Comment: look at a working example here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-employee-list-from-rest-api-rwlnnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It's not clear your question, but I'll assume following.

As you said, your response is an array of EmpResponse, so that means you have a list of EmpResponse. In every EmpResponse you have two properties: department and employee.

If you want the list of departments, should do:

```
this.deparments = this.empResponseList.map(emp => emp.department);
```

This will give you a list of all departments in the response.

You can use map function to extract any object property of an array.

[Map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Here an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qbbbxf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
this.paymentService.getAllEmps().subscribe((data) => {
           res: any;
           res = data;
           empResponseList = res; 
});
```